# Limit of Sequence with Function - Calculus

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, functions, convergence-divergence

Let $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $a<b$ and let $f:[a,b] \to [a,b]$ be a differentiable function, let $t \in [a,b]$, and consider the sequence $(x_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ defined by: $$\left\{\begin{matrix}
x_1=t & \\ 
x_{n+1}=f(x_n) & \forall n\geq 1 
\end{matrix}\right.$$

Now, suppose that there exists a point $\alpha \in [a,b]$ such that $f(\alpha)=\alpha$.

Let $0 \le q <1$ such that $|f'(x)|\le q$ for every $x \in [a,b]$ and $\lim_{n \to \infty}x_n=\alpha$

The above I have successfully proved, with some of your help!

Let $y \in \mathbb{R}$, and the sequence $(x_n)_{n=0}^{\infty}$:

$$\left\{\begin{matrix}
x_0=y & \\ 
x_{n+1}=\cos(x_n) & \forall n\geq 0 
\end{matrix}\right.$$

Prove that the sequence converge to a limit $0<\alpha<1$.

Any tips on how to start this proof?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Show that for $n>1$ you have $x_n\in [\cos 1,1].$

So apply your first part to $a=\cos1, b=1,f(x)=\cos x, t=x_2.$

**Lemma:** A fixed point $\alpha$ always exists for any continuous $f:[a,b]\to[a,b].$

**Proof:** If $f(a)=a$ or $f(b)=b$ then you are done.

Otherwise, let $g(x)=f(x)-x.$ Then $g(a)>0>g(b)$ so by the Intermediate Value Theorem, $g(\alpha)=0$ for some $\alpha.$ Then $f(\alpha)=\alpha.$

Comment: Thank you for the kind answer! I will try it and update :)

Comment: Hey, I have just proved it for $(x_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ but not $(x_n)_{n=0}^{\infty}$... Is there a theorem that shows that $(x_n)_{n=0}^{\infty}$ and $(x_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ converges to the same limit? Thanks!